# Why is Google BigQuery displaying incomplete results from the StackOverflow dataset?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to return all the tags and their excerpts from Google BigQuery's StackOverflow dataset. However, I find that some excerpts are missing.

```
SELECT

t.tag_name,

e.body AS `Excerpt`,

w.body AS `WikiBody`

FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.tags` AS t

LEFT JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.stackoverflow_posts` AS e

ON t.excerpt_post_id = e.id

LEFT JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.stackoverflow_posts` AS w

ON t.wiki_post_id = w.id

ORDER BY t.tag_name

LIMIT 10
```

For instance, the results of this query states that the tag [.d.ts] has no excerpt. However, checking it manually on SO, gives the following -
".d.ts is commonly used to define a typescript declaration file containing definitions for properties and functions. This gives the benefit to an IDE allowing it to provide intellisense and proper error messages when the declaration file is not adhered to."

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the wrong table on the join. You will want to use `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_tag_wiki_excerpt` instead.

```
select *
from `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_tag_wiki_excerpt`
where id = 58000712
```

| id | title | body |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 58000712 |  | .d.ts is commonly used to define a typescript… |  |